# Laravel display monthly datas

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am trying to display monthly consumption for all clients in a table and the month and year in the head should be from the database

[image]

This is my controller:

```
public function indexannuel()
{
    $clients = Client::all();

    // Initialize array to store monthly meter reading data for each user
    $indexMensuel = array();

    // Loop through each user
    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        // Initialize array to store monthly meter reading data for this user
        $indexMensuel[$client->user->fullname] = array();

        // Loop through the last 12 months
        for ($i = 12; $i > 0; $i--) {
            // Calculate the start of the current month
            $startDate = Carbon::now()->subMonths($i)->startOfMonth()->format('M');
            //$endDate = Carbon::now()->subMonths($i+1)->startOfMonth();

            // Get the meter reading for this user for the current month
            $indexDuMois = Bill::where('client_id', $client->id)
                            ->where('month', $startDate)
                            ->get('final', 'month', 'year');

            // Add the meter reading for this month to the monthly meter reading data array
            array_push($indexMensuel[$client->user->fullname], $indexDuMois);
        }
    }

    return view('bills.indexannuel', compact('indexMensuel'));
}
```

I'm stuck showing the right values in the right fields. Can you help me?

Comment: $indexMensuel[$client->user->fullname][<month>] = $value or $indexMensuel[$client->user->fullname][] = $value.

Comment: Also, consider optimizing your code. Potentially you are running tot clients x 12 queries to database

Comment: @Jack please can you help to optimize my code?

Comment: you should go with something like Client::with('bill', function($query) <...replace query without times here>)->get(); and then filter the collection by date.